# Dockerhub Repository Description

Tags: docker, markdown, dockerhub

Does anybody know how dockerhub manages the description on automatic build repositories?

[Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) has the nice feature that the README.md from the source repository is taken as the repository description. In practise the description of the repository is not always the latest README.md from the master branch. It appears to be quite random or related to latest builds.

Example Repository:

- /
- Dockerfile
- README.md

Branches:

- master

Tags:

- V1.0
- V1.1
- V2.0
- V2.1

Now the problem: If I put all Tags on Autobuild then it is not reproducable which README.md will be shown in the repositories description.

Is there a trick to it or is there an API can where I can set the description?

My wish is that always the latest commit of my master/README.md will be displayed!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [DockerHub doc](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#understand-the-build-process) mentions:

> The build process looks for a **`README.md` in the same directory as your `Dockerfile`**.

(see for instance [`tombatossals/dockerhub/nodejs`](https://github.com/tombatossals/dockerhub/tree/master/nodejs))

> If you have a `README.md` file in your repository, it is used in the repository as the full description.
>
> If you change the full description after a build, is overwritten the next time the Automated Build runs.
> To make changes, modify the README.md in your Git repository.

Note, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29135136/6309) by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452016/andy), this does not work for manual build.

> For manual builds (where you push your own image), Docker Hub does not peek inside your image and has no way to know about your Readme.
> You'll need to manually add your `Readme` text to the `Information` section.

---

The OP asks:

> Is there an API call where I can set the description of the repo?

Not that I know of ([Docker Hub API was deprecated in docker 1.8+](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker-io_api/))

---

[Issue 467](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/467) reports the same uncertainty:

> Sometimes the automated build system will still use the top-level `README` file.

And [issue 402](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/402) reports:

> "Every once in a while, the content in the Full Description and the `Dockerfile` page will be from an old release tag."

And then:

> "Has the specification for pulling `README`s changed? It now takes the top-level `README` from the source repository instead of from the directory where the `Dockerfile` is specified; considering a common use-case is a repository of Dockerfiles this has completely messed up the documentation."

[Issue 300](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/300#issuecomment-171808044) confirms:

> I notice two obvious failings here:

- a) The `README.md` is not respected in the sub-directory where the Dockerfile is
- b) Even if the `README.md` is at the repoository's top-level (as well as the Dockerfile) "sometimes" it is not read in and the description is left blank; even after force pushes to the underlying repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have builds on several tags and branches and the README.md seems random in this context. How can I control this?

Comment: @maybeg is your README near your Dockerfile?

Comment: The readme is right next to the Dockerfile in the same folder.

Comment: @maybeg And do you have a global README, at the root folder of your repo?

Comment: @maybeg that might be cause for uncertainty, as I see that https://github.com/tombatossals/dockerhub/tree/master/nodejs has none in its root folder.

Comment: Is there an API call where I can set the description of the repo?

Comment: @maybeg Not that I know of. I have edited the answer to include links to similar issues reported in the DockerHub project.

Comment: Currently, there is no mention of `README.md` in [DockerHub doc](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#understand-the-build-process) link.

Comment: @natenho Agreed. That was in 2016.

Comment: I've just opened [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/9202) to update that documentation, as I could not find the current process information.

Comment: @natenho Good initiative, thank you. I will follow this issue (https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/9202)

Comment: @blacklabelops There is an API you can use to push the README.md content. See my answer for a utility I created to handle that call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032775/dockerhub-repository-description/57671333#57671333

Answer (score 5):

[dockerhub-description](https://github.com/peter-evans/dockerhub-description) GitHub Action can update the Docker Hub description from a README.md file.

```
    - name: Docker Hub Description
      uses: peter-evans/dockerhub-description@v2.1.0
      env:
        DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
        DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY: peterevans/dockerhub-description
```

You can also use it independently of GitHub Actions in other CI tools.

```
    docker run -v $PWD:/workspace \
      -e DOCKERHUB_USERNAME='user1' \
      -e DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD='xxxxx' \
      -e DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY='my-docker-image' \
      -e README_FILEPATH='/workspace/README.md' \
      peterevans/dockerhub-description:2.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a tool to update the README, have a look at [docker-pushrm](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm). It is a Docker CLI plugin that adds a new command to Docker: `docker pushrm`  (for: *push readme*). To update the README on Dockerhub run:

```
docker pushrm my-user/my-repo
```

It uses the saved Docker login, so it "just works" after a `docker login`. It also supports other container registries (Quay, Harbor).

For CI use it's also available as a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/chko/docker-pushrm) and a [github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/update-container-description-action).

If you're looking for a technical answer, have a look at [the code](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm/blob/master/provider/dockerhub/dockerhub.go) of `docker-pushrm`. In short: You need to make a REST API request with your username/password [to get a JWT token](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm/blob/4dd1935835f67732abd55c6b0469b91a8d214a19/provider/dockerhub/dockerhub.go#L64). And then make another REST API request with that JWT token to [update repo info](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm/blob/4dd1935835f67732abd55c6b0469b91a8d214a19/provider/dockerhub/dockerhub.go#L114).